# PHP - Login with google api client problem

Tags: php, google-api-client

I just want to ask, why when i clicked the login with google button, it is not working and not shown anything at all?

Below is my code:

index.php file:

```
<?php require "../../Controller/SigninController.php"; use Ampp\Auth; use Ampp\Validate; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Sign In</title>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <form action="" method="post" class="frm">
                <h2>Sign In</h2>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php if (!empty(Auth::$error[2])) echo "<span class='err'>" . Auth::$error[2] . "</span>"; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="uname">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST["uname"])) echo trim($_POST["uname"]); else { if(isset($_COOKIE["memberid"])) echo $_COOKIE["memberid"]; } ?>" id="uname" class="form-control">
                    <?php if (!empty(Auth::$error[0])) echo "<span class='err'>" . Auth::$error[0] . "</span>"; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="upass">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="upass" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["memberpassword"])) echo $_COOKIE["memberpassword"]; ?>" id="upass" class="form-control">
                    <?php if (!empty(Auth::$error[1])) echo "<span class='err'>" . Auth::$error[1] . "</span>"; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="signin" name="signin" class="btn">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="chkinbox flt-left">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" class="chkbox" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["memberid"])) echo "checked"; ?>>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="chklblbox flt-left">Remember me</div>

                    <a href="../signup" class="goto flt-right">New user?</a>
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Google" name="btngoogle">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

startup.php file:

```
session_start();
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
```

SigninController.php file:

```
if (isset($_POST["btngoogle"]))
    {
        $client = new Google\Client();

        $client->setClientId("my_client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com");
        $client->setClientSecret("my_client_secret");
        $client->setRedirectUri("../../signin");

        $client->addScope("email");
        $client->addScope("profile");
    }

    if (isset($_GET["code"]))
    {
        $client = new Google\Client();

        $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET["code"]);

        if (isset($token["error"]))
        {
            $client->setAccessToken($token["access_token"]);
            $_SESSION["access_token"] = $token["access_token"];

            $google_service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
            $data = $google_service->userinfo->get();

            if (!empty($data["given_name"]) || !empty($data["family_name"]) || !empty($data["email"]) || !empty($data["gender"]) || !empty($data["picture"]))
            {
                if (Auth::RegisterProfile($data["given_name"], $data["family_name"], $data["email"], $data["gender"], $data["picture"]) &&
                    Auth::RegisterSessions($data["email"], "google")) 
                {
                    Redirect::TO("../home");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When run all above code, the browser just loading a little only and nothing more.

Your suggestion and advice really am appreciated.

Comment: Is the button inside a form, or is it just there on it's own? A single button without a form doesn't actually do anything, unless you have some JS event on it. You need to give us more info here.

Comment: It inside a form.

Comment: When you say "no working", do you mean that nothing happens when you click the button, or does it submit the form and nothing happens? Please explain the behavior in detail, since "not working" is too vague.

Comment: it is the second one. When i submit the form, nothing happens going on.

Comment: You're using `Auth` in both the HTML and your controller, but you only have `use Ampp\Auth;` in your HTML, not in your controller. You need to add that to every file that uses it You should check your web servers error log and see if there are any errors that will give you some clues.

Comment: I had do that just now. But it is still nothing happens too.

Comment: Did you check the web servers error log? Do you have any entries there?

Comment: Nothing's there. It is empty. I mean, in the apache error logs

Comment: The problem has been fixed already. The most thing is, i just forgot to put createAuthUrl() as my redirect. Thats why when i submit the form, the results is empty and nothing happened. For those who helping me, thank you very much from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it!